# i can't optimize this piece of code javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to optimize this, but i don't know how. I tried with a "for", but i couldn't.
Is there any function to shrink this ?
Sorry if the response is easy, i'm a newbie with coding.

```
if (avis1 == 1) {
    avis1Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis1 == 2) {
    avis1Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis1 == 3) {
    avis1Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis1 == 4) {
    avis1Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis1 == 5) {
    avis1Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avis2 == 1) {
    avis2Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis2 == 2) {
    avis2Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis2 == 3) {
    avis2Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis2 == 4) {
    avis2Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis2 == 5) {
    avis2Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avis3 == 1) {
    avis3Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis3 == 2) {
    avis3Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis3 == 3) {
    avis3Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis3 == 4) {
    avis3Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis3 == 5) {
    avis3Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avis4 == 1) {
    avis4Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis4 == 2) {
    avis4Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis4 == 3) {
    avis4Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis4 == 4) {
    avis4Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis4 == 5) {
    avis4Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avis5 == 1) {
    avis5Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis5 == 2) {
    avis5Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis5 == 3) {
    avis5Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis5 == 4) {
    avis5Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis5 == 5) {
    avis5Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avis6 == 1) {
    avis6Phrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avis6 == 2) {
    avis6Phrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avis6 == 3) {
    avis6Phrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avis6 == 4) {
    avis6Phrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avis6 == 5) {
    avis6Phrase = 'Très satisfait';
}

if (avisGeneral == 1) {
    avisGeneralPhrase = 'Très insatisfait';
}
if (avisGeneral == 2) {
    avisGeneralPhrase = 'Insatisfait';
}
if (avisGeneral == 3) {
    avisGeneralPhrase = 'Moyen';
}
if (avisGeneral == 4) {
    avisGeneralPhrase = 'Satisfait';
}
if (avisGeneral == 5) {
    avisGeneralPhrase = 'Très satisfait';
}
```

Comment: Ask on codereview please. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ever heard of `switch` - `case`? Also your `avisX` variables look like they should be an array

Answer (score 1):

Using an array should help a lot. Code example (incomplete):

```js
var avis1 = 5;
var phrases = ['Très insatisfait', 'Insatisfait', 'Moyen', 'Satisfait', 'Très satisfait'];
var avis1Phrase = phrases[avis1 - 1]; // javascript arrays always start at [0]
console.log(avis1Phrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could change your values from 0 to 4 instead 1 to 5 and use an [array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) as following:

```
var phrase = [
    'Très insatisfait',
    'Insatisfait',
    'Moyen',
    'Satisfait',
    'Très satisfait'
];
```

Then you can get the appropiate phrase by using:

```
var avis1Phrase = phrase[avis1];
```

Where avis1 should be a value between 0 to 4.

So, if you don't want to change your values then you could use a [JSON hash](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) instead of array as follow:

```
var phrase = {
    1:'Très insatisfait',
    2:'Insatisfait',
    3:'Moyen',
    4:'Satisfait',
    5:'Très satisfait'
};
```

In this case, you can get the appropiate phrase by using:

```
var avis1Phrase = phrase[avis1];
```

Where avis1 should be a value between 1 to 5.

Also, maybe you should to consider make an array or JSON hash for your vaiables avis1, ..., avis6, avisGeneral. I mean, something like this:

```
var avis = {
    1: my1stValue,
    ...
    6: my6thValue,
    General: myGeneralVaulue
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

i think you can possible use a switch statement

```
 switch (new Date().getDay()) {
case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
case  6:
    day = "Saturday";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object.

```
var text = { 
    1: 'Très insatisfait',
    2: 'Insatisfait',
    3: 'Moyen',
    4: 'Satisfait',
    5: 'Très satisfait'
};
```

Access

```
avis1Phrase = text[avis1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Since all the phrases for all the 'avis' are the same, you can reuse the same array.
var phrases = [
        'Très insatisfait',
        'Insatisfait',
        'Moyen',
        'Satisfait',
        'Très satisfait'
    ],
    // index starts at 0, so avis1 minus 1 gives the correct index.
    avis1Phrase = phrases[ avis1 - 1 ],
    avis2Phrase = phrases[ avis2 - 1 ],
    avis3Phrase = phrases[ avis3 - 1 ],
    avis4Phrase = phrases[ avis4 - 1 ],
    avis5Phrase = phrases[ avis5 - 1 ],
    avis6Phrase = phrases[ avis6 - 1 ],
    avisGeneralPhrase = phrases[ avisGeneral - 1 ];
```